# vsto - VB - find last cell from column in outlook addin

Tags: visual-studio, excel, vsto, outlook-addin, vba

How do you search for the last empty cell in an excel sheet from a vsto outlook addin?

I have the following code (not compiling)

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Dim ExcelApp As New Excel.Application
Dim ExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim ExcelWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet= ExcelWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Dim ExcelRange As Excel.Range = ExcelWorkSheet.Range("A1","A600")

Dim currentFind As Excel.Range = Nothing
Dim firstFind As Excel.Range = Nothing

currentFind = ExcelRange.Find("*", , Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, False)

            While Not currentFind Is Nothing

                ' Keep track of the first range you find.
                If firstFind Is Nothing Then
                    firstFind = currentFind

                    ' If you didn't move to a new range, you are done.
                ElseIf currentFind.Address = firstFind.Address Then
                    Exit While
                End If

                currentFind = ExcelRange.FindNext(currentFind)
            End While

ExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet.range(currentFind).Select()
```

I have updated it according to Scott Holtzman's comments but now I get an error message: HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to the question. This is to avoid confusion for future visitors. The changes aren't lost exactly, and you can pick them up in your [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46711104/revisions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I have the following code (now compiling!)

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Dim ExcelApp As New Excel.Application
Dim ExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim ExcelWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet= ExcelWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

Dim LastRow As Integer

LastRow = ExcelWorkSheet.Columns(1).Find("*", , , , Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious).Row

ExcelWorkSheet.Range("A" & LastRow).Select()
```

My error was in the actual property library choice. Beware to choose: 
**XlSearchOrder**.xlByColumns, Excel.**XlSearchDirection**.xlPrevious

Answer (score 0):

The code does not have the correct hierarchy according to the Object Model.

You cannot define a `Range` object without first defining a `Worksheet` object, which needs a `Workbook` object before it can be defined.

Try this:

```
Set ExcelApp = New Excel.Application

Dim ExcelWorkbook as Excel.Workbook
Set ExcelWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("myPath") 'actually opens a workbook to work with 

Dim ExcelWorksheet as Excel.Worksheet
Set ExcelWorksheet = ExcelWorkbook.Worksheets("mySheet")

Dim currentFind As Excel.Range = Nothing
Dim firstFind As Excel.Range = Nothing

Dim Fruits As Excel.Range = ExcelWorksheet.Range("A1", "A200")
Set currentFind = Fruits.Find("apples", , Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, False)


... 


Set currentFind = Fruits.FindNext(currentFind)
```

Comment: @Escounda - see my edits. First you need to declare and set the Application Object. Then the Workbook Object. Then the Worksheet Object. Then the Range Object

Comment: Thanks Scott Holtzman. I solved it by correcting the property of the .find() to: XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious